# Mac package postinstall script not running

Tags: mac, shell-script, package-maker

I have created a installer from package maker and scripts I specified scripts directory and postinstall script. When I installs the package it application installs fine but the scripts I specified is not running. Somewhere I read executable bit must be set but I did not find from to set this bit.

Following is the is my script. In this I am setting path variables in plist. Please guide me on this..

```
#!/bin/bash    
FILE=~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
PLIST=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

# if the file doesn't exist, try to create folder
if [ ! -f $FILE ]
then
  mkdir -p ~/.MacOSX
fi

# then just add entries (file will be created if it doesn't exist)
$PLIST -c "Add :Variable1 string 'Value1'" $FILE
$PLIST -c "Add :Variable2 string 'Value2'" $FILE
echo "Ended" >> ok.txt
exit 0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you execute the script directly in Terminal by entering its full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter the following:

```
chmod +x /Users/sandy/Resource/PostInstall.sh
```

This will set the executable flag on the file.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of hard-coding the path to `bash`.

Comment: Sorry, blame that on me :)