# How to make ffmpeg installer for OS X

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, installer

I have followed [this tutorial](http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html) to download, compile and install `ffmpeg` on Mac OS X. This worked fine but I want to make an universal installer from compiled source for all Mac machines.

Please help me out on this.

I am using OS X 10.6.7 and Xcode 3.2.5

Comment: From your history I think you [already know](http://superuser.com/questions/289920/mac-package-postinstall-script-not-running) how to use Package Maker. So what's your exact problem?

Comment: @slhck: yes I am familiar with package making but I am not sure how to use it in above case. I mean what to do after ./configure and make command to create installable package.

Comment: Well what exactly do you want to happen? If you say you already have the compiling done, do you need `ffmpeg` to be in the user's PATH only? Are there any other requirements?

Comment: I have done compiling as per the link but now I want to create a pkg to install ffmpeg on requird path, but I am confused how to do that. Earlier I created a package for java application using jar bundler and package maker which was quite easy I think but this case have c files etc.. so I am not sure how to create installer which should installs ffmpeg files to required places as "sudo make install" command do.

Comment: I'm not that much of a software developer, but `make install` will only do a few very basic things, like moving the binaries into the right place. Check the `makefile` provided with `ffmpeg` to see what it does and then just replicate that in a post-installation shellscript.